# Query matching some but not others

Tags: neo4j

So I have some nodes in there that are pretty basic. If I query certain nodes by values, it'll get a match, where other I will not. In this photo you can see the first query (at the bottom) shows 3 nodes that exist. The next query shows that I was able to pull back the one with the value 'seafood'. Then the next one gets a goose egg on 'dining' when clearly it's there. I also get nothing when I query 'restaurant'. I tried even copy and pasting the value right out of the first query just to make sure I wasn't misspelling something. What gives?

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have whitespace characters before or after some property values. If so, this query will return `false` in the second column of the `dining` and `restaurant` rows:

```
MATCH (c:Category)
RETURN c.Value AS value, c.Value = TRIM(c.Value) AS ok;
```